# WPF ZIndex not being applied

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, z-index

A much simplified version of my XAML has a layout like this

```
<Border ..>
<StackPanel ..>
    <DockPanel Panel.ZIndex="0">
    ..
    </DockPanel>
    <Border Panel.ZIndex="100">
        <StackPanel>
            <Border Style="{StaticResource InfoBorder}" Focusable="False">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Margin="0,-5,0,0"  Focusable="False" >INFO.</Label>
                    <Grid Margin="20,0,0,0"  >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Name}" Panel.ZIndex="100" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"  />

                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <DockPanel Panel.ZIndex="0" Height="30" Background="{StaticResource titleBarBlue}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{StaticResource titleBarBlue}">
            <Image Source="..."  />
            <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content=".."/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

The issue I'm having is the ZIndex is not being applied to the Borders children and as such the ContentControl content is being displayed behind the final dockpanel.  How can I apply a zindex so that the content controls contents always render above the last button/image?

Comment: All items that you apply `ZIndex` to are children of `StackPanel` which does not put children on top of each other, like `Grid` or `Canvas`, only below or next to. How can `ContentControl` display below `DockPanel`?

Comment: If I make the outside StackPanel a Grid and create 3 rows I'm still having the same problem

Comment: If you change outer `StackPanel` to `Grid` then `Border` comes on top. Set `Background` of `DockPanel`, `Border` and ` DockPanel` to different colours and you see it as well.

Comment: Aha. And if I remove that outside border everything behaves as I wish. How can I keep the outside border or what control must I change border to be to have a similar look but keep the ZIndex behaviour of the children